# Use email based self registration in webservice

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to register a user using webservice and was successful in creating the user. Now I want to use the email based self registration as auth plugin. By default 'manual' registration is used.  So I changed `$user1->auth = 'manual';` to `$user1->auth = 'email';`  but is not working. In both case after registration the user is able to login without confirmation. Please help.

Comment: you could always add a new field within the table branded `activated` and default it to 0 until they have verified which you could then trigger it to update `activated` to 1

Comment: @Option        Thanks. My question is how we can send a confirmation email to user. Moodle already have this functionality. But when using webservices how we can do it?